# How to access your Amazon Echo Alexa history/events like IFTTT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

IFTTT seems to use "Login with Amazon" to access either a) Alexa events or b) Alexa history. How is this possible?

Is there a special permission configuration step when setting up "Login with Amazon"? Or is there a special parameter to supply when triggering the login page?

Note this is completely different to normal "Account Linking".

Login page says:

- When you click "Okay", we'll provide IFTTT:
- Your name: XYZYour e-mail address: xyz@example.com
- Access to your Alexa information (like To-do lists) to trigger recipes you create.
- Permission to publish information to, and write and modify information on, Alexa in order to execute recipes you create.

This is the login screen:

[image]

Note the extra permissions on this image:

[image]

Full walk-through here: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-empower-the-amazon-echo-with-ifttt/

Answer (score 0):

IFTTT has their own special deal with Alexa & Login with Amazon to get their own login scope. If you look under the hood, the permissions scope they initially request is "ifttt".